# How secure is the Heroku Piggyback SSL

Tags: django, ssl, heroku

I deployed a Django app on Heroku that exposes an API which I call from an Android app. I wonder now how secure the Heroku Piggyback SSL encryption is. I transmit data that has to be secure in the URL itself.

A request might look like this one

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/friends?authToken=xyz
```

Obviously no one should be able to sniff the URL and get the authToken from it. Is that true for the Heroku Piggyback SSL? If yes, is there an advantage of using the SSL Endpoint add-on with my own SSL certificate?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as secure as Heroku's infrastructure, anyway--obviously you're trusting both their internal configuration and Amazon's cloud not to leak your visitors' information.

That aside: Any SSL configuration should protect the privacy of your URLs in transit. You're probably fine.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to hear :-)